# SearchView null pointer

Tags: java, android

SearchView не получается инициализировать, выдает null:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation_drawer, menu);
    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.groupVsbl, true);
    if(listFragment != null && listFragment.isVisible()) {
        menu.add(0, R.id.action_search, 0, "").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
                | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation_drawer_search, menu);

        MenuItem itemSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) NavigationDrawer.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(itemSearch);
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(NavigationDrawer.this.getComponentName()));
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

    }

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

И собственно само меню:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:title="Title" />
</menu>
```

В строке, где идет проверка на null (**if (searchView != null)** ), searchView  всё равно остается null, несмотря на то что я выше её объявил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `itemSearch != null`, значит `R.id.action_search` в меню несколько и возвращается первый и не тот что надо.

Comment: в R.id.action_search лишь один элемент <menu> <item android:id="@+id/action_search"/> </menu>

Comment: Судя по коду, там несколько меню разных инфлейтится.

Comment: Да, там идет проверка, если фрагмент виден - отображать одно меню, иначе другое.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо, обратился по id( MenuItem itemSearch = menu.getItem(4);)